# How can I make a button in one activity to modify components in other

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I'm trying to make some layouts and listviews gone and visible by pressing a button located in another activity.

Also I want to input some text in an edittext located in the same activity as the layouts

I've looked all over this place and I found several examples but I just couldn't make them work so I'm posting my own code.

```
        btnnext1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        val next1 = Intent(this, next1::class.java)
        startActivity(next1)
        categories.visibility = View.GONE
        listacats.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ListView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        e_search.setText("blackcat")
    })
```

From what I found out this can be achieved by using intent.PutExtra, but I just couldn't make it work.

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main task is pass "blackcat" to another activity, you could do like this:
In MainActivity:

```
        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("passed_str", "blackcat"); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

In OtherActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        String receivedStr = getIntent().getStringExtra("passed_str");//receive string

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setText(receivedStr);

        categories.setVisibility(View.GONE); //change wiget's visibility
        listacats.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
```

Comment: If I understand well, this will modify the text in the edit text when pressing the button in previous activity, and the visibility of the listviews will change once the new activity is loaded. 

The thing is I need the visibiity to change only when pressing the button too, not when the new activity is loaded, coz I dont want it to change the visibility everytime the activity is loaded.

Only when the button in the previous activity is pressed.

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: @GaboWalker when click button in MainActivity, you could write a boolean value in shared preference xml file, and in OnResume() method of OtherActivity, judge this boolean value and choose whether show or hide widgets.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @GaboWalker You are welcome, maybe upvote my answer if its helpful, thanks! :)